# JButton breaks my Keylistener

Tags: java, swing, listener, key-bindings

JAVA USING NETBEANS

Hello stackoverflow, i have a problem i would like help with. In a nutshell, I have a mouselistener and a keylistener on a jpanel, everything works fine except when i press one of my jbuttons, then the keylistener goes AWOL. Can any1 explain the problem, is the panels focus now on the buttons instead of the keyboard, im at a lost.

Here is the code, if somethings are not reference, assume its are there the entire panel code was 500+ long so i cut quite a bit.

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
package tankgame;

public class TankPanel extends JPanel implements KeyListener, 
MouseListener,MouseMotionListener

{
JButton back,shop, menu, health, speed, rapidfire, shootradius;

TankPanel()
{
    setLayout( null );

    addMouseListener(this);
    addMouseMotionListener(this);

    addKeyListener(this);
    setFocusable(true);


    shop= new JButton("SHOP");
    shop.addMouseListener(this);
    shop.setBounds(400,0, 80,15);
    add(shop);

}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent k)
{
        char c = k.getKeyChar();

        if(c=='u')
        {
            u++;
            System.out.println(u+" = u");
        }
        if(c=='i')
        {
            i++;
            System.out.println(i+" = i");
        }
        if( c == 'd' )
        {
            if(Ptank.pic==PlayerTankE)
            {
                if(Ptank.move==true)
                {
                    Pbarrel.x+=Ptank.speed;
                    Ptank.x+=Ptank.speed;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(Ptank.pic==PlayerTankN || Ptank.pic==PlayerTankS)
                {
                    Ptank.x = Ptank.x - 5;
                    Ptank.y=Ptank.y+5;
                }

                Ptank.setPic(PlayerTankE);
                Ptank.width=35;
                Ptank.height = 23;

            }
        }
        setFocusable(true);
            repaint();
    }

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent k)
{
}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent k)
{
}



public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
{    
    //Invoked when the mouse button has been clicked (pressed and released)



}
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
{//Invoked when the mouse enters a component.
}

public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
{ //Invoked when the mouse exits a component.
}

public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
{//Invoked when a mouse button has been pressed on a component.
    if(e.getSource()==back)
    {
        System.out.println(456);
        System.out.println(back.getLocation().x + " "+back.getLocation().y);
    }

    else if(e.getSource() == menu)
    {
        changebuttons("menu");
        System.out.println(456);
        System.out.println(menu.getLocation().x + " "+menu.getLocation().y);
    }
    else if(e.getSource() == shop)
    {
        changebuttons("shop");
        System.out.println(456);
        System.out.println(shop.getLocation().x + " "+shop.getLocation().y);
    }
    else if(e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1)
    {
        destpoint= new Point();
        destpoint.setLocation(mousex, mousey);
        origin = new Point();


        }


        for(int i = 0; i< Ptank.rapidfire; i++)
        {
            if (origin.distance(destpoint) <= 100 && origin.distance(destpoint) >= 50)
            {
                Bullet add = new Bullet(this,destpoint);
                add.getOrigin(origin);
                add.setPic(PlayerBullet);
                add.width=4;
                add.height=4;
                bulletList.add(add);
            }
        }

    }
}

public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
{//Invoked when a mouse button has been released on a component.
}

public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
{//Invoked when a mouse button is pressed on a component and then dragged.

}

public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
{
    //Invoked when the mouse cursor has been moved onto a component but no buttons 
        Cursor cursor = Cursor.getDefaultCursor();
        //you have a List<Polygon>, so you can use this enhanced for loop
        cursor = Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.E_RESIZE_CURSOR);
        setCursor(cursor);
        mousex=e.getX();
        mousey=e.getY();

}

public void changebuttons(String x)
{
    if(x.equals("shop"))
    {
        menu.setBounds(720, 0, 80, 15);
        health.setBounds(0, 0, 125, 15);
        speed.setBounds(150, 0, 125, 15);
        shootradius.setBounds(300, 0, 200, 15);
        rapidfire.setBounds(500, 0, 150, 15);
        shop.setBounds(1000, 0, 150, 15);

    }


 }
```

Comment: You should also be using proper Java naming conventions. You should also be using layout managers. You are taking too many shortcuts.

Comment: Also, you should not be using MouseListeners on a JButton. You should be using ActionListeners. You really need to take some time to learn how to use Swing the way it was designed to be used. I suggest you start by reading the Swing tutorial. You've been given the link to the section on "Using Key Bindings". Other sections like "Using Layout Managers" and "How to Write an Action Listener" would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 5):

KeyEvents are only generated on a component that has focus. When you click on the button is now has focus to key events won't be generated on the panel. You need to add:

```
panel.requestFocusInWindow()
```

in your ActionListener to give focus back to the panel.

However the better solution is to use [Key Bindings](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) as you can add bindings to a KeyStroke even when the component doesn't have focus.

Comment: Rob, since he's only listening for a few distinct keys, wouldn't he be better off using a higher level construct such as key bindings rather than a KeyListener? Pete

Comment: Yes, Key Bindings is the better approach.

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly what i needed, your the best.

Comment: @Forkedwizard: see camicrk's reply to my question. Again, you want to use key binding. What if you add other components to your GUI? What if you want the focus to be somewhere else while still being able to listen for key strokes?  Yes it is more work, but in the long run it will be worth your while.

Comment: @Hover and Camickr: I see you alls point, and maybe i will implement keybindings later on, but this game is due tomorrow and im just trying to get it presentable and working lol, thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use a KeyListener which requires the component be focused to work. Instead consider using Key Bindings.  You can find out how to use these guys at the Swing tutorial: [How To Use Key Bindings](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).  If you need more specific help, you will want to post a much smaller bit of code than you show above, code that is self-contained and will actually compile and run for us, an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Thanks for input, but I didn't want to have to recode much :) anyhow its answered

Comment: @Forkedwizard, that is the wrong attitude. Now is a good time to learn how to use Key Bindings for a simple application. All Swing components use Key Bindings, your code should be no different.